# Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I am having a layout file and 5 buttons -- 1 for next and 2 for previous etc. Application runs fine, when I click first button, it loads the image correctly, then as I click another button, it gives the error -`Caused by java lang Out Of Memory Error`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

ImageButton btn1;
ImageButton btn2;
ImageButton btn3;
ImageButton btn4;
ImageButton btn5;
ImageButton btn6;
ImageButton btn7;
ImageButton btn8;
ImageView image1;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addListenerOnButton();
    addListenerOnButton2();
    addListenerOnButton3();
    addListenerOnButton4();
    addListenerOnButton5();
    addListenerOnButton6();


}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    btn1= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.show);
        }

    }
    );
}

public void addListenerOnButton2() {

    btn2= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view)
                                {
                                    setContentView(R.layout.k2);
                                }
                            }
    );
}

public void addListenerOnButton3() {
    final Context context =this;
    btn3= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view)
                                {
                                    setContentView(R.layout.k3);
                                }
                            }
    );
}

public void addListenerOnButton4() {
    final Context context =this;
    btn4= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view)
                                {
                                    setContentView(R.layout.k4);
                                }
                            }
    );
}

public void addListenerOnButton5() {
    final Context context =this;
    btn5= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view)
                                {
                                    setContentView(R.layout.k5);
                                }
                            }
    );
}

public void addListenerOnButton6() {
    final Context context =this;
    btn6= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view)
                                {
                                    setContentView(R.layout.k6);
                                }
                            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Post a stacktrace please

Comment: share xml and stacktrace

Comment: May be your Image size is too large.

Comment: can you tell us whats size of your images. cause i am having sure of that it is caused by image size.

Comment: 250KB pic size..its due to pic size ..so tell me how can i clear memory when clicked another button

Comment: `System.gc()` this command will forcefully call garbage collector. its not good manner to use that. and also it won't work all time. what i suggest is that if you can reduce size than reduce size of image.

Comment: i have 10 pics. memory full error occur when after i try to load 2nd image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the whole layout instead of changing the image. When you do that, garbage collector is not called and you should be calling it on your own. Since it's not called, you are going to get that error pretty soon.

Do it like this instead

```
int[] imageArray = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, ... };
```

and when you click a button, just do

```
  btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view)
                                {
                                    someImageView.setImageResource(imgageArray[0])
                                }
                            }
```

Also make sure you don't use too big images. The take up a lot of memory.

Comment: the image size not more than 250kB

Comment: That is not equal to the amount of memory it will use! It will use much more than that. Use memory monitor and see for yourself.

Comment: Call System.gc() , but I suspect you are leaking memory the way you are doing this.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().gc();    finally i got solution..it works fine